# Is there any situation when oil increases friction?

Tags: friction

I have read everywhere and tried myself to experience oil smoothening surface interfaces, thereby reducing friction. I was curious if there are instances where oil increases the friction between those two substances.

Assume substances to be solids.

Answer (score 1):

Friction is caused by surface irregularity or imperfections between the two surfaces and weak electromagnetic forces between molecules, such as experienced in hydrogen bonds and Van der Waal bonds..

Oil has high viscosity so they create a film between the two surfaces that does not get squeezed out under pressure. This film does not let the surface irregularities of both solid surfaces to come too close to each other, thus reducing friction.The more perpendicular pressure between the two surfaces, the more viscous the lubricant needs to be

Viscosity is, essentially, fluid friction. Like friction between moving solids, viscosity
transforms kinetic energy of motion into heat energy. Heat is energy of
random motion at the molecular level, so to have any understanding of how this energy
transfer takes place, it is essential to have some picture, however crude, of solids and/or liquids sliding past each other as seen on the molecular scale. 
Liquid Zero FrictionThe mixture of acid and polyhydroxy alcohol exhibits zero friction. This acid solution has been found having superlubricity properties between a glass plate and silicon nitride. **If any type of lubricant is used here,it will increase friction instead of decreasing because of friction viscosity**

Comment: Using something a little less esoteric, would adding oil on top of ice also increase friction of something sliding across it?

Comment: All oils have different values of friction coefficients. It will depend on the molecular attractions also,like wan der waal force and hydrogen bonding